# Change table background color when change row value PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a table on PHP like bellow and I need that, when the first column changes value, the line changes color.
E.g.: at table in example, first and second lines will be red, third line will be blue, fourth red again and so on

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Today</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>Tomorrow</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>Yesterday</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>Next Saturday</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can do in CSS, jQuery or another language, but I need help.

Thanks

Comment: How does the value get changed? Your sample code contains no PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: Provide us some PHP or Javascript code you're using to change the values please.. In any case, jQuery or javascript would be the solution, unless you want to reload the page every time a value gets changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$bgcolor       = ""; 
$new_bgcolor   = "#F1F1F1";
$bgcolor_trans = "";

if ( $current_row > $last_row ){
   $bgcolor_trans = $bgcolor;
   $bgcolor       = $new_bgcolor;
   $new_bgcolor   = $bgcolor_trans;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set two classes for TRs, e.g. rowOdd & rowEven

```
$days = array(1=>'Day1', 2=>'Day2', 3=>'Day3');
$trClass='Odd';
echo '<table>';
foreach ($days as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<tr class="row'.$trClass.'"><td>'.$key.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    if ($trClass=='Odd') { $trClass='Even'; } else { $trClass='Odd'; }
}
echo '</table>';
```

CSS

```
.rowOdd { background-color: #F00; }
.rowEven { background-color: #0F0; }
```

Comment: The line color needs to change according the first cell value changes too. Your example will print each line with a color (striped).

Comment: how many possible values you have? If there are not too many maybe instead of rowEven & rowOdd you can have class="row<?=$cellValue?>" and create the necessary classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag veriable for count.

For example:

```
$count = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $count++;
    if(($count%2) == 0){
        echo '<tr style="background:#FFF">';
        echo    '<td>';
        echo    '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<tr style="background:#000">';
        echo    '<td>';
        echo    '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```