# Change row background in HTML table depending on the value of the first column

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-color

This is my part of a table (with a number of rows that I don't know before I generate the table) that an external script creates:

```
<table id='testTable'><thead>
<tr>
<th align="center">Header 1</th>
<th align="center">Header 2</th>
<th align="center">Header 3</th>
<th align="center">Header 4</th>
<th align="center">Header 5</th>
<th align="center">Header 6</th>
<th align="center">Header 7</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">AAAA</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
<td align="center">Field 2</td>
<td align="center">Field 3</td>
<td align="center">Field 4</td>
<td align="center">Field 5</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">AAAA</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
<td align="center">Field 2</td>
<td align="center">Field 3</td>
<td align="center">Field 4</td>
<td align="center">Field 5</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">BBBB</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
<td align="center">Field 2</td>
<td align="center">Field 3</td>
<td align="center">Field 4</td>
<td align="center">Field 5</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">BBBB</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
<td align="center">Field 2</td>
<td align="center">Field 3</td>
<td align="center">Field 4</td>
<td align="center">Field 5</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">CCCC</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
<td align="center">Field 2</td>
<td align="center">Field 3</td>
<td align="center">Field 4</td>
<td align="center">Field 5</td>
<td align="center">Field 1</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to change the background colors for alternate rows using 2 colors (grey and white, for example) considering the value of the first  as the key. In the data above, it would be something like:

```
1st row --> white
2nd row --> grey
3rd row --> grey (because the key is still "BBBB")
4th row --> white
```

I checked [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773156/change-table-background-color-when-change-row-value-php) but I was not able to use it, so it would be great to have step-by-step indications to edit the html or the CSS that I use to style the table (if necessary, I can post the content of the CSS too).

Comment: I don't think this is doable using only CSS, you'll need some JS.

Comment: can u use Jquery??

Comment: Yes, I can use it but I'm basically starting on these topics and therefore I really have no clue how to do that on my own.